# MarkLogic remove parent node that have different child

Tags: marklogic

I try to remove parent `<Book:PDF>` that have sub-child `abstract`.     Is there any way to resolve it?

`xdmp:node-delete($xml/Book:PDF)` will remove all `Book:PDF` nodes

`xdmp:node-delete($xml/Book:PDF/html:html)` removes sub-nodes of **abstract** but all `Book:PDF` nodes remain intact.

sample `$xml`:

```
<Lib:Record Type="Bio" xmlns:lib="http://fxlib.net/lib/record">
  <Book:PDF>
       <html:html>
          <abstract>
              ....
              ....
          </abstract>
      </html:html>
 </Book:PDF>
 <Book:PDF>
       <html:Authors>
          <Author>
              ....
              ....
          </Author>
      </html:Authors>
 </Book:PDF>
</Lib:Record>
```

Correct Result:

```
<Lib:Record Type="Bio" xmlns:lib="http://fxlib.net/lib/record">   
   <Book:PDF>
       <html:Authors>
          <Author>
              ....
              ....
          </Author>
      </html:Authors>
   </Book:PDF>
</Lib:Record>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include a sample of the command that you ran?

Comment: So, you are just looking to delete the `Book:PDF` elements that have an `abstract` descendant?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the `Book:PDF` elements that have an `abstract` descendant, then use an XPath selecting the `Book:PDF` with a predicate to test whether they have any `abstract` descendants:

```
xdmp:node-delete($xml/Book:PDF[.//abstract])
```